# How to get distinct value and specific count from a query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

Suppose I have the following table "Person":

| id | name | friends |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | matt | jim |
| 1 | matt | ray |
| 1 | matt | ray |
| 2 | tim | fry |
| 3 | sally | jack |
| 3 | sally | tim |
| 4 | matt | harold |

I want to output the following:

1 matt 2
2 tim 1
3 sally 2
4 matt 1

*Note that entries can have duplicates, so for example we see "1 matt 2" instead of "1 matt 3", but name is not unique, so since there are two matts with different ids, we also see "4 matt 1".

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT(distinct friends)
FROM Person;
```

But COUNT doesn't work how I had expected in this scenario. Is there a way to get my expected output?

Answer (score 3):

you should make a group by the id and the name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. Tested on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c45a700009241dcefff1cdfe1d2e48f), try this:

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT(distinct friends)
FROM Person
GROUP BY id, name;
```